# Azure VPS as TCP server

Tags: c#, azure, sockets, tcp

I'm using an Azure VPS to host a TCP server (raw sockets) but the external client is timing out when it tries to connect to the server. I've already opened the TCP ports on Azure Portal.

It works locally so it can't be a problem on the code.

(Note that the address shown in the server print is just the local address, the client is pointing to the server external address)

Server running:

[image]

Client timeout:

[image]

Comment: Downvotes without an explanation are the worst.

Comment: Did you check your security groups ?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Post the code, using the code formatting button, as text in the question.

Comment: Sorry for that, my intention was actually to show the timeout error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out the problem was the VM firewall. Just added the inbound rule and it worked!